# Swagger UI page cannot be found[errorCode 404]

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, swagger-ui, resteasy

I have implemented basic jaxrs restEasy application and I want to generate a swagger.json and swagger-ui for all the API's.I'm able to generate swagger.json but getting error **swagger-ui page not found error everytime**. I'm not sure how to resolve it. Can anyone please help me out.Added swagger-jaxrs dependency. Bean configuration with correct basepath and host and added resources SwaggerSerializers and ApiListingResource in application class and I'm able tp generate swagger.json and for swaggerui I have added swagger file in webapp directory and trying to access html file but getting this error.I'm trying to access using localhost:8080/chatbox/docs/swaggerui or localhost:8080/chatbox/docs/swaggerui/index.html but none is working but localhost:8080/chatbox/swagger.json I'm getting. Please help

Github code:: github.com/IAMAKANSH/jaxrs_easyrest/tree/master

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here. What container are you running in? Whatever that `BeanConfig` is, it doesn't seem to be registered anywhere so it's not doing anything.

Comment: Also please copy and paster your code here. Do not post images of code. Thanks

Comment: I'm running this on tomcat 9

Comment: Please find link for the code
https://github.com/IAMAKANSH/jaxrs_easyrest/tree/master

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Could you please check my codebase and guide me.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Could you also please check my code and guide me